# external USB HDs for data storage on ZFS with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: zfs

I have three 4T USB HDs (to be used for data storage) and I'd like to know if I can create a ZFS pool. I understand there RAIDZ that would do this but not sure it can be setup with external USB HDs
Thank you, ioan

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to do this, but there are some things one must be aware of:

1. Use the drive device identifiers, such as  /dev/disk/by-id, /dev/disk/by-partlabel or /dev/disk/by-partuuid rather than the /dev/sd* name because USB drives may change their /dev/sd* names depending on the enumeration on boot.
2. Try to spread the USB connections across different USB controllers if possible. as an optimization step.

Comment: Which of these non-sd* IDs are the best for this, i.e. the least likely to change or impossible to change?